# I need some help understanding why the count does not get reset to 0 in this every time it recursively runs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

```
const theTruthCounts = (arr) => {
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    let element = arr[i]

    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      let result = theTruthCounts(element)
      count += result
    } else {
      if (element) {
        count++
      }
    }
  }
  return count
}

theTruthCounts([0, [true, ['yes']]]) //Output: 2
```

I understand most of this and how it works. With recursion though, I seem to get confused at the recursive statement where it says "let result = theTruthCounts(element)" and "count += result".
Even if the element is truthy, and it adds 1 to the count, wouldn't count get reset to 0 each time and so the return would just be 0?

Comment: `count` is local to *each* invocation of `theTruthCounts`, as with any other function.

Comment: With recursion, it is really best if you can use the debugger and go through this yourself. That will lead you to the best understanding

Comment: So when I did the debugging, I came to this answer, though i'm not sure if it's the right one. My understanding is that each time it runs recursively, "result" is holding the count from each run of the function and they all get added together in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you run your method `theTruthCounts`, each layer that you go into recursively has it's own `count` variable which is returned in the end.

So let's take your for loop at index 1.

The `element` is going to be `[0, [true, ['yes']]][1] = [true, ['yes']]`

Then, `let result = theTruthCounts(element)`

What this does is, brings you into another theTruthCounts with it's own count variable. So ultimately from first layer to second layer it looks like when it reaches index 1.

```
theTruthCounts = ([0, [true, ['yes']]]) => {
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < [0, [true, ['yes']]].length; i++) {

    let element = arr[i]

    if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      let result = theTruthCounts = ([true, ['yes']]) => {
      let count = 0; //your second count variable here in second layer

      for (let i = 0; i < [true, ['yes']].length; i++) {

        let element = arr[i]

        if (Array.isArray(element)) {
          let result = theTruthCounts(element)
          count += result
        } else {
          if (element) {
            count++
          }
        }
      }
      return count

      } //exit second layer back to first recursive layer here with result


      count += result
    } else {
      if (element) {
        count++
      }
    }
  }
  return count
}
```

So hopefully you can see from this, everytime you you go into a `theTruthCounts(element)`, there's a new count variable within that local scope.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's what I assumed was happening in the end, but I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Every execution of the function has its own, separate `count` variable, and that execution only counts the truthy values in the `arr` that is given to it. So it is normal that it starts from 0. After it has done its job, it returns that count. The *caller* adds that result to its own `count` variable, which potentially increases in each iteration of the loop.